# MySQL slow query optimize countries percentage query

Tags: mysql

This query took 100 seconds to run. I've indexed every column that is used for conditions or joins and still it is taking too long to run. How can I write this query in a way that will run efficiently?

```
SELECT e.earning_country, c.country_name, COUNT(e.earning_id) AS views, ROUND(100 * COUNT(e.earning_id)/b.total, 2) AS percentage
FROM earnings AS e
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT COUNT(earning_id) AS total
FROM earnings
WHERE earning_paid = 1 AND earning_ad_id = 1 AND earning_referral_id = 0) AS b

INNER JOIN countries as c
ON c.country_id = e.earning_country_id

WHERE earning_paid = 1 AND e.earning_ad_id = 1 AND earning_referral_id = 0
GROUP BY e.earning_country
ORDER BY percentage DESC
```

EXPLAIN Result:

```
"id",   "select_type",  "table",        "type",         "possible_keys",                                                                                "key",                                                              "key_len",  "ref",                          "rows", "Extra"
1,      "PRIMARY",      "<derived2>",   "system",       NULL,                                                                                           NULL,                                                               NULL,       NULL,                           1,      "Using temporary; Using filesort"
1,      "PRIMARY",      "e",            "index_merge",  "earning_referral_id_index,earning_country_id_index,earning_paid_index,earning_ad_id_index",    "earning_referral_id_index,earning_paid_index,earning_ad_id_index", "4,1,4",    NULL,                           362698, "Using intersect(earning_referral_id_index,earning_paid_index,earning_ad_id_index); Using where"
1,      "PRIMARY",      "c",            "eq_ref",       "PRIMARY",                                                                                      "PRIMARY",                                                          4,          "site.e.earning_country_id",    1,      NULL
2,      "DERIVED",      "earnings",     "index_merge",  "earning_referral_id_index,earning_paid_index,earning_ad_id_index",                             "earning_referral_id_index,earning_paid_index,earning_ad_id_index", "4,1,4",    NULL,                           362698, "Using intersect(earning_referral_id_index,earning_paid_index,earning_ad_id_index); Using where; Using index"
```

Comment: To be clear, you have a 3-way index on `earning_paid`, `earning_ad_id` and `earning_referral_id`.  Then indexes on `earning_country`?  Also, how much faster is it if you just take out the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: I have individual indexes on all 4. Table has millions of rows - not sure I could have a 3 way index - do you think it would help?

Comment: How many rows in the table and how many rows are returned by the query?  `earning_id` should also be indexed, but I'm not 100% how much that will help with the `ORDER BY` in a very large data set.

Comment: earning_id is the primary key. Basically I am really struggling with this stats system. I have tried to implement a NOSQL solution but the google-cloud datastore and bigtable are virtually inaccessible from php.....

Comment: MySQL will only use 1 index per table. So it you have indexes on the 4 columns which are used for the joins only one of those indexes will be used. If you have an index covering all 4 columns then that might be used instead.

Comment: Can you do an EXPLAIN of the query and post the results please

Comment: @Kickstart added the explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL will only use 1 index per table. So it you have indexes on the 4 columns which are used for the where clauses and joins only one of those indexes will be used. MySQL will chose the index it thinks is best, but that may be far from perfect.

With your query I suspect earning_paid is a flag so on its own probably of little use for an index (on average half the records on the table will have each value). With earning_ad_id and earning_referral_id you appear to be checking for 0 which is I presume a default value for each, and again each probably cover a large number of rows. Combined together those 3 probably do have some use as an index.

earning_country is probably useful as an index for the aggregate function but won't help with narrowing down the number of rows.

If you have an index covering all 4 columns then that might be used instead

Set up an index covering earning_paid, earning_ad_id, earning_referral_id AND earning_country (in that order).

EDIT

Small explanation

Say you have a phone book. To find names this is ordered by the surname (which is in effect an index). You scroll through until you find the name you want, and being in name order this is easy.

If you want to find someone with the name Smith then you can jump to that quickly.

If you know their first name then you can easily find that in the list of Smith. So John Smith (no doubt lots of them) can be found.

However if you wanted to find a Doctor called Smith and you didn't know their first name you could have an index on Surname and Title. If it were a rare surname and a common title it would be best to have surname first and title 2nd, if the surname is common and the title is rare then it would be best to have the title first and the surname 2nd.

In this case the index would just just be a list of each surname and title with a pointer to the rest of the record.

If you wanted a count of all the Doctors called Smith then you can get this just looking at the index without needing to look up the rest of the record.

Comment: So wait, the order of an index matters as well?

Comment: Wouldn't the group and lookup be applied as separate operations?  (hence you'd want two different indexes?)

Comment: Yes, the order of the index does matter as well. In this case the first 3 fields will exclude a lot of records, while the 4 is useful for grouping the fields, and that can largely be done just on the index itself (without using the table) as the records to use and process are all in order within the index. @ebyrob - MySQL will not use 2 different indexes for the 2 operations.

Comment: So I order by the cardinality, with the larger ones first? Or with the larger ones last?

Comment: Depends! In this case lower cardinality first as you are using the low cardinality fields to exclude records. But normally high cardinality (uncommon) fields first.

Comment: @kickstart My little brain is about to explode!  Aren't we always trying to exclude irrelevant records? Finding needles in haystacks?

Comment: Yes, which is why you normally want the higher cardinality fields first in the index. In this case part of the index is also required for the grouping but despite having a high cardinality (I think - lots of countries) it is not of any use for narrowing down the data required as you are processing all countries.

Comment: So essentially I should order by what % of the records each index is likely to remove.....starting with ones that will remove the most? In this case earning_paid might remove 50% of the records so it goes first.

Comment: Yes, for general indexes you want to exclude the most that you can as early as you can. You do not exclude any records based on country though (which is probably going to have a reasonable cardinality). But you GROUP BY earning_country which presumably has a 1 to 1 relationship with earning_country_id.

Comment: Well, one country can have many earnings. Countries is just a table of countries with ISO codes and some metadata. Should I also keep my individual indexes for ORDER BY type processes? I mean, they would be run seperatly and could use a different index couldn't they?

Comment: As far as I know, no they will not be used in this query (they might well be useful in other queries on their own). While 1 country can have many earnings, with the index covering 4 columns with the country last you can exclude any records you want to exclude first, and then all the records you want to process are in the index one after the other, and in the order you are going to need them to group them for the counts (ie, all the records for 1 country followed by all the records for the next country).

Comment: I see, so I should order the index in the logical way in which SQL would best exclude data, and then how it would carry out ordering etc. Wow, I feel like I have really learned a lot!!

Comment: Largely yes. And if you are lucky the entire query can be done just accessing the index and not touching the table.

Comment: How does MySQL know which index to use though - like if I design specific indexes for certain queries....

Comment: Magic (or so it seems sometimes). It keeps statistics of cardinality, etc and decides from these statistics which index to use for a particular query. You should run ANALYZE TABLE occasionally to rebuild these statistics as they get out of date. For example say you entered all your records for 1 country MySQL would have stats showing that country is a poor index to use. If you then inserted the records for all the other countries it might still be using the stats to say country is a poor choice when now it is actually a good choice.

Comment: Oh great, omg I keep asking questions, but does ANALYZE TABLE lock the table for a time? Is it safe to run?

Comment: Think it does lock things for a while, but not certain. Not been an issue when I am using it, but most of our tables are updated batch wise rather than continuously from online transactions.

Comment: @Kickstart thanks a lot for your help. I feel like my brain has got slightly bigger! I have a headache now. Tomorrow I'll back up and then start optimizing my database! :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an answer, but try running the following query to get an idea of how fast you can work with this data in a simple manner:

```
SELECT
  e.earning_country
  ,c.country_name
--  ,COUNT(e.earning_id) AS views
FROM earnings AS e
INNER JOIN countries as c
        ON c.country_id = e.earning_country_id
WHERE earning_paid = 1 AND e.earning_ad_id = 1 AND earning_referral_id = 0
GROUP BY e.earning_country_id
;
```

Try running it both with the `views` line commented in and out and see the difference in performance, Note: I noticed you were grouping by `earning_country` not `earning_country_id` in your original query.

PS - If this query runs faster, you could do the rest of your calculation in memory to get the total, percentage and sort it.

If you want an idea of how big a three-way index would be, try running the query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT earning_paid, earning_ad_id, earning_referral_id)
FROM earnings;
```

Index size should be based on the variability of the data, not the size of the table.

If `earning_id` is never `NULL` (and primary key shouldn't be) then you can get a performance boost by using `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(earning_id)`.

Comment: You mean the cardinality of the data when you say variability?

Comment: create index three_way on earnings (earning_paid, earning_ad_id, earning_referral_id); .....like that?

Comment: @AmyNeville Looks about right.  Kickstart seems to know more about the details of optimization though.

Comment: I also ran the DISTINCT query to include a fourth index earning_country_id and produced 44,000 or so (that's on a table with 4 million records). Could I try a 4 way index therefore?

Comment: @AmyNeville Always good to try more things.  Might as well add both indexes and see which gets used.  Note: I think getting a timing on the simplified query is also important, it would give us an idea of your system's possible performance.

Comment: Yes, that would probably help. Put earning_country_id after the other 3 (probably should add that as a field that you SELECT and GROUP BY as well just for clarity)